# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}}{x-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate:

> $$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}}{x-2}$$

My attempt:
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac { \frac 1 x -\frac 1 2 }{ x-2 } } =\lim_{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac { \frac { 2-x }{ 2x }  }{ x-2 }  } =-\lim_{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac 1 {2x} =-\frac 1 4} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: What made you think it was incorrect in the first place, and why would you want to verify with us if you know you did all the work correctly? You can verify it once again by yourself.

Comment: If you just want to check your result, I suggest [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=lim+(1%2Fx-1%2F2)%2F(x-2)+as+x+-%3E+2)

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your answer is correct. You can also do it by using L'Hospitals rule.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{2}}{x-2}&=\lim_{x\to 2}\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right) \\ &=-\dfrac{1}{4}\end{align}\tag*{}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, note also that by definition of derivative with $f(x)=\frac1x \implies f'(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}}{x-2}=f'(2)=-\frac14$$

Answer (score 0):

["Yes"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x---%3E2%20of%20((1%2Fx)-(1%2F2))%2F(x-2)) would suffice as an answer.